# Unknown method syntax

Tags: c++

```
static void Initialize(void* (*allocPtr)(size_t), void (*freePtr)(void*))
```

I have never seen a method taking this type of syntax before. Is it casting? Can anyone shed some light on this? I would search other answers but I am not sure how to phrase it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters are [function pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer).

Comment: Ah makes sense, that was my second guess. Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how are function pointers different from callbacks?

Comment: @Mr.Llama, Function pointers are just one way to accept or store a callback. Others include `std::function` or a generic parameter that should be any callable object.

Comment: @Mr.Llama A callback is typically implemented as a function pointer, but a function pointer doesn't have to be a callback, it can serve any purpose you want it to. It's like the "a square is a rectangle, but a rectangle is not necessarily a square" argument.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the two arguments to the `Initialize` function as the following.

The first argument is a "function pointer to a function that takes a `size_t` argument and returns a `void*`"

The second argument is a "function pointer to a function that takes a `void*` argument and has no return (return is `void`)"